# How to integrate with our web application?

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to docusign, i try with sample c# code for signin using access token and send file to singing. Everything working in c# sample web application. But i want to integrate with my web dms application, which i want to pass one or more files to docusign and get back that files once signed in vb.

For this what can i use? Code is in c#, so can i use REST Api or SOAP api which use in my web application.

Here i attach c# sample code what i tried.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    // Embedded Signing Ceremony
    // 1. Create envelope request obj
    // 2. Use the SDK to create and send the envelope
    // 3. Create Envelope Recipient View request obj
    // 4. Use the SDK to obtain a Recipient View URL
    // 5. Redirect the user's browser to the URL

    // 1. Create envelope request object
    //    Start with the different components of the request
    //    Create the document object
    Document document = new Document
    {
        DocumentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ReadContent(docName)),
        Name = "Lorem Ipsum",
        FileExtension = "pdf",
        DocumentId = "1"
    };
    Document[] documents = new Document[] { document };

    // Create the signer recipient object 
    Signer signer = new Signer
    {
        Email = signerEmail,
        Name = signerName,
        ClientUserId = signerClientId,
        RecipientId = "1",
        RoutingOrder = "1"
    };

    // Create the sign here tab (signing field on the document)
    SignHere signHereTab = new SignHere
    {
        DocumentId = "1",
        PageNumber = "1",
        RecipientId = "1",
        TabLabel = "Sign Here Tab",
        XPosition = "195",
        YPosition = "147"
    };
    SignHere[] signHereTabs = new SignHere[] { signHereTab };

    // Add the sign here tab array to the signer object.
    signer.Tabs = new Tabs { SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere>(signHereTabs) };
    // Create array of signer objects
    Signer[] signers = new Signer[] { signer };
    // Create recipients object
    Recipients recipients = new Recipients { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };
    // Bring the objects together in the EnvelopeDefinition
    EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        EmailSubject = "Please sign the document",
        Documents = new List<Document>(documents),
        Recipients = recipients,
        Status = "sent"
    };

    // 2. Use the SDK to create and send the envelope
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
    apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
    EnvelopeSummary results = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(accountId, envelopeDefinition);

    // 3. Create Envelope Recipient View request obj
    string envelopeId = results.EnvelopeId;
    RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
        ClientUserId = signerClientId,
        AuthenticationMethod = "none",
        UserName = signerName,
        Email = signerEmail
    };

    // 4. Use the SDK to obtain a Recipient View URL
    ViewUrl viewUrl = await envelopesApi.CreateRecipientViewAsync(accountId, envelopeId, viewOptions);

    // 5. Redirect the user's browser to the URL
    return Redirect(viewUrl.Url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign in recent months released an item to the Visual Studio Marketplace: [https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.docusign-vscode-extension#:~:text=The%20DocuSign%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Extension%20configures%20your%20project%2C%20adds,to%20make%20DocuSign%20API%20calls](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DocuSign.docusign-vscode-extension#:%7E:text=The%20DocuSign%20Visual%20Studio%20Code%20Extension%20configures%20your%20project%2C%20adds,to%20make%20DocuSign%20API%20calls).

When adding it to your project, you'll be prompted to help setup OAuth, but more importantly you'll be given a list of available Code Examples that are compatible with your current project. These code examples operate in a very similar way to the launchers we have on GitHub, but more importantly: you can download them and then reference the examples directly from your existing project.

Comment: Hi i want , i need to pass file to docusign and once signed file need to store in local folder  (server) ,instead of file replied in mail.

Comment: DocuSign takes a wide variety of file types. Typically when sending to our system they're provided in a raw binary or base64 form. If you'd like to retrieve your completed document after the fact, you can do this by making a GET call to the envelope's document URIs. We have a code example you should be able to import into your existing project that does this: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-download-envelope-documents

Comment: Hi can you provide some vb samples for integrate Docusign flow which pass files and get back ? , 
1.Bcz we have Asp.net with vb , so how to pass files and once finished get back that file.We already created Sandbox Demo Account,pls provide some samples which used in vb, may be with the help of SOAP or REST api .
Sending file we will convert to raw binary or base64 form.So which are api used to Get Access Tocken,Pass file and get back file once signed. 
2.And currently we hard coded Accesstoken,ID, but how to popup login Docusign screen .